# 2010 WF creates new list item, person fields are overwritten with System Account

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a SPD 2010 WF running on List A that creates a new item in List B.  Within the 2010 "Create List item" step, I set a person field in List B to a specific user value.  Once List B is created, the field value = System Account.  Please do not suggest using InfoPath or 2013 WF.  We use 2010 because we need to include the attachments and the "trigger Create Event" flag that has been removed from 2013.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because the user who runs that workflow doesn't have enough permissions, so, Application Pool account performs this.

Look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3050853/a-sharepoint-designer-workflow-activity-uses-the-system-account).

Comment: The link suggests that you might be correct.  Do you have instructions on how to make sure the user has enough permissions?

Comment: By default, in a SPD workflow there is no way to check if a user has specific permissions, but you could install [this](https://spdactivities.codeplex.com), and [this](https://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Is%20User%20a%20member%20of%20a%20SharePoint%20group&referringTitle=Home) to check if a user has read/contribute. Installation is a little bit messy

Comment: Thanks Sergio.  The codeplex site mentions that it has been shutdown.

Comment: Yes, but you can download anyway.